# Issue with overflow property of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have hosted my website on a test server at medexcel.comeze.com  .

The issue is, when I hover over a menu button in the top bar, the overflow of the top div isn't hidden anymore and the bottom right corner of the red menu button is visible.

How do I fix this?

CSS for top is:

```
#top{
    @include green-gradient;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px rgb(56, 56, 56);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and for menu,

```
.myButton{ 
    @include red-button;
    border-radius:50px 0px 50px 50px;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #810e05;
    float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="top">
    <div class="small-8 columns">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns" id="menu">
        <div class="myButton">Menu</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some HTML code as well.

Comment: I believe your issue is the float. Removing the element from the standard flow so its not affected by the 'overflow:hidden'. If you can position it inline etc it might fix the issue

Comment: I added HTML @PeterStuart

Comment: I tried removing float and aligning it to right. The issue persists.

Comment: seems to work fine in firefox. The display is all wrong in IE though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: static` to `.myButton`.

```
.myButton{ 
    @include red-button;
    border-radius:50px 0px 50px 50px;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #810e05;
    float:right;
    position:static;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested this in Chrome on your site using Inspector and it worked fine.

Comment: Try closing the inspector and hover on the button.